# PHP Regular Expression - {0,1}, ?, etc

Tags: php, regex

Regular expression pattern:

```
[[1-9]-]?[a-zA-Z1-9]
```

Shouldn't the following strings match?:

```
2-
5-
2-S
5-t
S
t
```

What am I not understanding here?

---

Also Tried:

```
[[1-9]-]{0,1}[a-zA-Z1-9]
[[1-9]-|][a-zA-Z1-9]
[[[1-9]-]|][a-zA-Z1-9]
```

---

### Goal

Trying to come up with a pattern for:

```
1st character = Number 1-9
2nd character = always "-"
3rd character = Alphanumeric (all cases, 1-9)
4rd character = Alphanumeric (all cases, 0-9) Repeat X number of times
OR
1rd character = Alphanumeric (all cases, 1-9)
2rd character = Alphanumeric (all cases, 0-9) Repeat X number of times
```

(i realize i haven't implemented the repeat portion in the code given here yet)

---

Comment: i want [[1-9]-]? to give me (a Number '1-9' AND "-" ) OR empty.
currently it gives me (a Number '1-9' AND "-" ) but not the EMPTY option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work for you (assuming X=8):

```
^([1-9]-)?[a-zA-Z1-9][a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$
```

Comment: doesnt ([1-9]-)?
tend to match all permutations of [1-9] and "-"??
as in: "2-","2","-", etc.?

Comment: Tried it out.
it seems to match the entire thing or ONLY the first two characters, i.e. "2-".
Instead, i need the first two characters of "2-" to be optional

Comment: Actually, when I try it in my real code, it worked fine.
Trying it in: http://www.phpliveregex.com/ did not work fine... im probably using it incorrectly? but thank you.

Do you think you can give me a quick rundown on why its ([1-9]-)? instead of [[1-9]-]?

Comment: Yes because `[[1-9]-]?` is not correct since that makes `[[1-9]` a character class followed by literal `-]` instead of `1-9` followed by literal `-` only.

Comment: can you suggest a way to make the repeating end portion be for either {8} or {6}? (and not 7)

Comment: That would be: `^([1-9]-)?[a-zA-Z1-9][a-zA-Z0-9]{6}([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})?$`